# Having "To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared" message and can't find how to fix that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

i'm new to coding and i'm trying to plot a few graphs for my lessons. My code was working very good, and when I tryed to fix some bad written words in my titles, it didn't work anymore, I started getting "To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared". I researched a lot on the web looking for a solution, but couldn't find anything conclusive, anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

df = pd.read_csv('Assignment_base de dados - Sheet1.csv')
df.head()

df.drop(columns='ID_Pedido')

df.isnull().sum()

df = df.dropna()
df.isnull().sum()

high_nps = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
low_nps = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

high_nps.update(dict(df[df['NPS'] >= 9].groupby('Plano fechado').count().reset_index()[['Plano fechado', 'NPS']].values))
low_nps.update(dict(df[df['NPS'] <= 6].groupby('Plano fechado').count().reset_index()[['Plano fechado', 'NPS']].values))
total_nps = dict(df.groupby('Plano fechado').count().reset_index()[['Plano fechado', 'NPS']].values)

nps_score = {council: (high_nps[council] - low_nps[council]) / float(total_nps[council])  for council in total_nps}

print(nps_score)

nps_score.update((x, y*100) for x, y in nps_score.items())
NPS_items = nps_score.items()
NPS_list = list(NPS_items)

dfNPS = pd.DataFrame(NPS_list).set_index(0)

print(dfNPS)

dfCount = df.groupby('Plano fechado').count()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))
dfCount.plot.bar(ax=axes[0],subplots=True, xlabel='', legend=None, fontsize=15, rot=0)
dfNPS.plot.bar(ax=axes[1],subplots=True, xlabel='', legend=None, fontsize=15, rot=0)
axes[0].set_title('Quantidade de contratações por plano', fontsize=18)
axes[1].set_title('NPSs de cada Plano', fontsize=18)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the dataset and [keep you code minimal to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also an image of the current and expected output would be helpful

Comment: Also please post the full trace back.  It’s hard to guess where this originates from

Comment: Thanks for all aswers! Ended getting what I needed, just realized I forgot to assign the dataframe changes in a few lines, when I made that change I could get the right output

Comment: @eliodmsr Consider deleting this question then?